# Variable outside function is reset every time during recursion

Tags: r

I am a beginner at R, so please pardon me if there is a key programming construct about R that I am not understanding.

I have the following code:

```
tab_level <- 0

print_tree <- function (node_index) {
    cat (tab_level)
    cat ("\n")
    # Past the tree domain
    if (node_index >= 2^depth ) {
        tab_level <- tab_level - 1
        cat ("\n")
        return()
    }

    # Print the value in the node
    # Tabs

    #cat(node_index)
    for (i in 0:tab_level) {
        cat("\t")
    }

    tab_level <- tab_level + 1

    print_tree(2*node_index)
    print_tree(2*node_index + 1)
}
print_tree (1)
```

However, when I do this and read the `cat` outputs, tab_level is 0 every single time, in the output. Am I understanding R incorrectly, and how it works with variable scope? I come from a Java background, if that helps at all, and I'm assuming it works similarly to Java.

Comment: put tab_level inside the function, or make it an argument.

Comment: @cory Why do I need to do this though, wouldn't it still work since it's in the parent call's scope?

Comment: Check out the "Function environments" section here for more detail... http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: It's horrible practice, but you can change your `tab_level <- tab_level + 1` to `tab_level <<- tab_level + 1` and it would work.

Comment: it's not that the variable was reset, it's just that it was never changed in the global environment, as cory says `<<-` will allow you to change values in the parent environment

Comment: In short, R doesn't care that your function is recursive. It just sees another function call. It calls it in the upper level environment, and in that level, tab_level is still 0.

Comment: @6pool I see, why is it considered bad practice though? In my case, I actually need to be changing a global variable (and it will actually save through the stack calls).

Comment: Maybe you meant to ping @cory, I didn't say it was bad practice.  Perhaps he was referring to the use of global variables in general.

Comment: <<- finds the variable in the global environment and sets it there. It creates side effects and makes R not the nice functional language we know it to be. It should be used exceedingly sparingly. Usually when I find myself reaching for <<- I wonder whether the code would be better written in an OO language like python.